# Check if another user has a session in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know we can see if the current user is logged in with `Auth::check()` but I would like to know how we can take another users id and see if they have an authenticated session or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably at least 2 methods:

1) When authenticated user runs any action you register datetime in `users` table (for example in `last_activity` column). Now you can verify which users have active session comparing `last_activity`  + lifetime (from `config/session.php`) is is >= NOW() - if it's it means user has active session. Of course in this case you should also take care of user logging out to not do it for users why logged out.

2) You can change default session driver to `database` (first run `php artisan session:table`) and you will be able to get those information from session users table.